# I can't change the boolean values in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, boolean

I am doing a small MVC project. I want when I click button, Vip status of a user that logging in will change. (Base on session). But when I click, nothing changes.

Stored procedure:

```js
CREATE PROCEDURE setupVip2 
 @MaKhachHang nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
 UPDATE khachhang 
    SET IsVip = 1 
    WHERE MaKhachHang = @MaKhachHang
END
GO
```

Model:

```html
public void setupvip(string id)
{
    re.setupVip2(id);
}
```

Controller:

```html
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult KetQua(string id)
{
    khachhang kh = re.khachhangs.Find(id);
    return View(kh);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KetQua(string id, khachhang c)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MuaVipModel mm = new MuaVipModel();
            mm.setupvip(c.MaKhachHang);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        
        return View(c);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(c);
    }
}
```

View:

```html
@model Model.khachhang
    @using RaovatThuCung.Common

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "KetQua";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var session = (UserLogin)Session[CommonConstants.USER_SESSION];
}

<h2>KetQua</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("KetQua","MuaVip",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Thanh toán thành công</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.Hidden("session.UserID",session.UserID)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Kích hoạt vip" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

- Is it wrong at Html.Hidden? If not, please show me my fault . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HttpPost action method, you are passing the `MaKhachHang` property of  the 
`khachhang` object. That means, you need to send that value form the submitted form.

You may keep the value of `MaKhachHang`  in a hidden input field **inside the form** tag. You can use the `HiddenFor` helper method to generate the hidden input element for that property.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.MaKhachHang)
```

This will render the value from the `khachhang` object which you are passing from your GET action. It might not be the current user, but the one your `Find` method is returning. If you want to use the logged in user id from session, do not try to pass it to UI and pass it back to server (***because anything on the client browser can be updated by user using browser dev tools***). Simply use it in your server code.

Simply read the `UserLogin` from session and use `UserID` property value when calling `setupvip` method, inside the HttpPost action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KetQua(string id, khachhang c)
{
    var session = Session[CommonConstants.USER_SESSION] as UserLogin;
    // to do : Do null check before accessing session 
    var mm = new MuaVipModel();
    mm.setupvip(session.UserID);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");    
}
```

Comment: But this will change by user is logging in? or not?

Comment: No. This will be the value from the object you are getting in your GET action using the `Find` method in your GET action method.

Comment: can you suggest me how to do that? :(

Comment: do what ? you want to use the current logged in user's id ?

Comment: Yes. i want to use current user logged in

Comment: And in a view i must use @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.MaKhachHang) ?

Comment: No. If you are not using `MaKhachHang` property value anywhere in your HttpPost action method, no need to include that in the form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.MaKhachHang)
```